# Extract number from the property inside interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So a message type can be let's say 'MESSAGE_TYPE_9', and I would like to extract only "9"... Is this possible to do inside the template?

I tried this but it throws an error(Unexpected token / ):

```
{{ message.type.match(/[0-9]+/g) }}
```

Comment: RegExp literal are not supported by the templating language. They should be on your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple ways to do it. I assume you want do it in HTML **ONLY**. You can use `split` method as follow,

```
{{ message.type.split("_")[2] }}  // split gives you array and 2 is the index of the element that you are looking for
```

**OR**

if the message is of fixed length/size, you can use **charAt**, **splice**, **substring** function(s),

```
{{message.type.charAt(13)}}   OR  {{messsage.slice(13)}}  OR {{message.type.substring(13)}}  OR {{message.type.substr(13)}}
```

Comment: If default change detection strategy is used, the functions will be triggered in each change detection cycle.

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't think RegEx patterns are supported in the template.
2. Try to avoid calling functions in interpolations and property-bindings. It'll be triggered in each change detection cycle in case of default CD strategy.
3. You could either do it in the controller or write a quick pipe for it.

Try the following

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'getNumber', pure: true })
export class GetNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): string[] {
    return /\d+/g.exec(value);
  }
}
```

Component

```html
{{ message.type | getNumber }}
```

It's a very minimalist pipe that extracts any number of numbers that occur first in the string. Eg. `'MESSAGE44_TYPE_9'` will return `44`. You could adjust the RegEx pattern accd. to further requirements.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5u9bjr)